# How to validate powershell conditional syntax?

Tags: powershell, static-analysis

Is there a syntax checker for conditionals in PowerShell?
This code will skip the conditional

```
if ($templList -ne $null -and $templList.items.Length > 0) {
  $templID=$templList.items[0].id
  write-host $templList.items
}
```

because the '-gt' is substituted with '>'.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Strictly speaking, you're looking for a *semantics* checker, given that your code is *syntactically correct*.

The problem here is that while the code was formally correct, it doesn't do what you *intended* it to do.

**[PSScriptAnalyzer](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/PSScriptAnalyzer) (PSSA) is a [linter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lint_(software)) for PowerShell**, and it is integrated into the [PowerShell extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.PowerShell) for [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/).

It would catch your problem, emitting the following message:

> Did you mean to use the redirection operator '>'?
>   The comparison operators in PowerShell are '-gt' (greater than) or '-ge' (greater or equal).

---

#### Use in Visual Studio Code:

- Install the [PowerShell extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.PowerShell).
- Once installed, with your script opened for editing, you'll see the `> 0` part underlined, and hovering over it shows the message as a tooltip.
- You can see all messages for the current file in the Problems view (<kbd>Ctrl-Shift-M</kbd> or, via the menus, `View > Problems`), which incidentally, will show you that PSSA found additional potential problems with your code snippet.
- To configure what rules to apply (which potential problems to warn about), use `>PowerShell: Select PSScriptAnalyzer Rules` from the command palette.

  - The rule names, such as `PSAvoidGlobalVars`, are mostly self-explanatory; the [rules documentation](https://github.com/PowerShell/PSScriptAnalyzer/tree/master/RuleDocumentation) describes them (without the `PS` prefix); and there's also a [best practices topic](https://github.com/PowerShell/PSScriptAnalyzer/blob/master/PowerShellBestPractices.md).
  - **Important**:

    - After checking / unchecking (or pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> on) the rules of interest, be sure to press <kbd>Enter</kbd> on the `Confirm` menu item at the top, otherwise your changes won't take effect.
    - As of v2019.11.0, these selections *aren't persisted* (are remembered in the current session only) - see [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/PowerShell/vscode-powershell/issues/823)

Note that PSSA **also offers automatic *(re)formatting* of PowerShell code** (<kbd>Alt-Shift-F</kbd> or, via the command palette, `>Format Document`).

---

#### Stand-alone use:

- Install the `PSScriptAnalyzer` module from the PowerShell Gallery; e.g.:

  - `Install-Module -Scope CurrentUser PSScriptAnalyzer`
  - The module comes with the following cmdlets:

    - [`Invoke-ScriptAnalyzer`](https://github.com/PowerShell/PSScriptAnalyzer/blob/master/docs/markdown/Invoke-ScriptAnalyzer.md) ... lints script files.
    - [`Invoke-Formatter`](https://github.com/PowerShell/PSScriptAnalyzer/blob/master/docs/markdown/Invoke-Formatter.md) ... reformats code passed as a *string*.
    - [`Get-ScriptAnalyzerRule`](https://github.com/PowerShell/PSScriptAnalyzer/blob/master/docs/markdown/Get-ScriptAnalyzerRule.md) ... lists standard and optionally custom analyzer rules.
- Pass your script's path to the `Invoke-ScriptAnalyzer` cmdlet to perform linting.

With your code, you'd see the following output (having been given a script named `pg.ps1`):

```
RuleName                            Severity     ScriptName Line  Message
--------                            --------     ---------- ----  -------
PSPossibleIncorrectUsageOfRedirecti Warning      pg.ps1     1     Did you mean to use the redirection operator '>'? The
onOperator                                                        comparison operators in PowerShell are '-gt' (greater than)
                                                                  or '-ge' (greater or equal).
PSPossibleIncorrectComparisonWithNu Warning      pg.ps1     1     $null should be on the left side of equality comparisons.
ll
PSUseDeclaredVarsMoreThanAssignment Warning      pg.ps1     2     The variable 'templID' is assigned but never used.
s
PSAvoidUsingWriteHost               Warning      pg.ps1     3     File 'pg.ps1' uses Write-Host. Avoid using Write-Host
                                                                  because it might not work in all hosts, does not work when
                                                                  there is no host, and (prior to PS 5.0) cannot be
                                                                  suppressed, captured, or redirected. Instead, use
                                                                  Write-Output, Write-Verbose, or Write-Information.
```

Comment: I have it installed in VS code with, "powershell.scriptAnalysis.enable": true; and it reports 'No problems'. However, changing '-ne' to != showed a problem.

Comment: @un-CharlieH: Interesting - are you trying with the exact same code as in your question? I definitely see the warning re `>`  in VSCode 1.39.2, with the latest PowerShell extension 2019.9.0 and its bundled PSScriptAnalyzer 1.18.3

Comment: I have PS 6.1 installed and VS Code automatically uses it. I switched to PS 5.1 and see it now! Thanks for pointing the way.

Comment: @un-CharlieH: Glad to hear it; I do also see the warning with the latest 6.x Core version, 6.2.3