# PowerShell equivalent of Shellcheck

Tags: powershell, shellcheck

I found this https://github.com/PoshCode/PowerShellPracticeAndStyle but I was wondering if there's anything like [shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) but for PowerShell.

Comment: For CLI use, there is PSScriptAnalyzer. It is also integrated into the PowerShell extension for Visual Studio Code - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58529223/45375).